# Can you decrease an index of a list once it is ceated?

Tags: python, list

I am creating a code that works like the game 'floor is lava'
There is a list containing everyone's lives but I need to decrease the index corresponding to whether the player is out or not :

`lives = [5 for x in range(players)]`

there is a variable that makes a list of yes or no for who is out:

```
outers = list(input("Input a list of yes or no for who is out: "))
```

doing this following code **didn't** work:

```
for x, y in zip(outers, lives):
    if x == "yes":
        lives[y] -= 1
```

Can someone help please.

Comment: I think you've picked the wrong data structures, a `dict` or `collections.Counter` would be easier to increment/decrement

Comment: would you be able to create a `dict` that has a certain amount of keys depending on a variable `players` like I have with the list `lives`

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lives = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
outers = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
lives = [i-1 if j == 'yes' else i for i,j in zip(lives, outers)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> lives = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> outers = ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no']
>>> lives = [i-1 if j == 'yes' else i for i,j in zip(lives, outers)]
>>>
>>> lives
[4, 5, 4, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: unfourtunetly not :(

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: possible the OP actually intends to decrement on a "no" result, but this syntax is spot on.

Comment: here is a segment of the code output using this:          `Input a list of yes or no for who is out: ['yes', 'no', 'no']
[5, 5, 5]`

Comment: @ProgrammingIsFun what do you mean by decreasing indexes? 0 becomes -1? so the first element in the list becomes the last one?

Comment: i want the value of the index to change

Comment: @ProgrammingIsFun Please answer my questions, so I may help.

Comment: @ProgrammingIsFun try printing `outers`. If you are inputting it as you suggest, it does not contain the values you are expecting.

Comment: @asongtoruin You were right all the values in `outers` were not as i expected

Comment: try `outers = input("Input a list of yes or no for who is out: ").split(",")` and form your input as `yes,no,no` (i.e. with no spaces or other characters). This answer will work in that case.

Comment: It still didn't work, the `outers` list wasn't as i expected but this code:                                          `lives = [i-1 if j == "yes" else i for i, j in zip(lives, outers)]`

Comment: @ProgrammingIsFun edited my comment as I'd misordered the solution

Comment: still no change to lives

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that y is an element of lives and not an index.

I believe

```
for k in range(len(outers)):
    if outers[k]=="yes":
        lives[k]-=1
```

will give you what you want